# How to format new measure (not column) in power BI as percentage?

Tags: powerbi, dax

When I create a new measure with formula, i.e. sum(col1)/max(col2), it automatically converts the result into #.#% format. Strangely, it doesn't happen all the time; sometimes it just gives result #.## format.

Any idea of how to format a new measure (not column) to be treated as percentage?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Power BI there is a option in the taskbar when you enter your measure.

In Power Pivot for Excel you can select the format directly in the measure editor (Or editor for calculated fields. The name depends on your version of Excel)

If you want to take over manually you can also use the `Format()` formula:

```
= FORMAT(Sum(Table[Field]),"0.00%")
```

Answer (score 17):

There is another way to convert the value into % in Power BI Desktop.

1. Create a measure with simple `Divide` formula
2. Click on the name of measure in `FIELDS` section
3. Go to `Modeling` tab and select % sign in `Formatting` section

The field will automatically be converted to % value.

[image: Convert to % in Power BI]

Comment: but this thing convert 2 into 206.07% How can we fix it into 2%

Comment: @user8205502 I assume you can choose how many decimals you want in the combo box to the right of %.