# Power Pivot - Dax Measure sums up wrong

Tags: excel, pivot, dax, powerpivot

together

somehow my pivot table is currently crashing. The table is structured as follows:

[image]

Area, Code and QTY1 are defined by the data model. QTY2, Min and Performance are measures.
QTY2 sums all codes for defined filters from another table. Min calculates the lower value of QTY1 and QTY2.
Measure Performance calculates the ratio of Min to QTY1.

Unfortunately, the sum of Min from Excel will be incorrect. Also, the mean or the sum of performance is also wrong.

```
Formumlar QTY2: =CALCULATE(SUM(tbl2[QTY]);FILTER(tbl2; tbl2[TYP]<>"11"))
Formular MIN: =MIN([QTY2];[QTY1])
Formular Performance : = [MIN]/[QTY1]
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?
How can the mistake be avoided?

Edit:
The following approach sums up the right volume for [Min].
But it is not showing the accurate average of 37%. It sums up the divided value.

```
[Performance]=SUMX(tbl_General;DIVIDE([QTY2];[QTY1];BLANK()))
[Min]=SUMX(tbl_General;(MIN([Qty1];[Qty2])))
```

Why is that so?

[image]
Best regards
Joshua

Comment: Please share the formulas leading up to, and including the formula that is summing incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Formulars are now included

Comment: There are some useful links in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953022/finding-cummulative-sum-of-max-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is an example of where [SUMX](https://radacad.com/sum-vs-sumx-what-is-the-difference-of-the-two-dax-functions-in-power-bi) is needed.

You've stumbled on the difference between the *aggregation* of an expression and the *sum* of values.

Something like `SUMX(dim_Tbl, DIVIDE([MIN], [QTY1], BLANK()))` should work

EDIT:

After seeing the edit on the OP, the following measures should work.

```
Min = SUMX(tbl_General;(MIN([Qty1];[Qty2])))
```

and

```
Performance = DIVIDE([QTY2];[Min];BLANK())
```

In general, 'X' measures are used to iterate over a table and sum the table whereas 'normal' measures are used for recalculations in sums. Your Performance measure you want to recalculate for the total, so don't use SUMX, your Min Measure, you want as a sum of the previous values, so do use a SUMX.

Comment: Thanks Frostytheswimmer. Please take a look at my edited post. It sums up in the right way for [Min], but the avergage at for the whole data set is false. It should be 37%. It also sums up the everage per row.

Comment: Ok thanks, and how can I a get the ratio between Min und Qty 1?

Comment: See my edit -and pm for more conversation if needed.- Can't PM on SO apparently so continue in comments I guess..

Comment: Thanks, that work perfect! How can I get the value of 0% for rows with no value for [Min]?

Comment: @joshua1990 Change DIVIDE([QTY2];[Min];BLANK()) to DIVIDE([QTY2];[Min];0). The last parameter in the DIVIDE Function is the alternate result space.

Comment: I allready tried. But it dont work. I get no value on rows/ codes, where no value in qty2 is

Comment: I would hazard to guess that it is with the formatting then. You want a formatting like  "0.0%;-0.0%;0%"

Comment: Yes. Where can I declare that specific format? I tried to change the format for the values on 0.0%;-0.0%;0% but there is no change

Comment: You have to change the formatting on the measure its self.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353064/how-to-format-new-measure-not-column-in-power-bi-as-percentage

Comment: It is not working. I just get more rows shown. There is no change on the format. I still get no value. Is there a way to show "0" on the [QTY2] measure (QTY2: =CALCULATE(SUM(tbl2[QTY]);FILTER(tbl2; tbl2[TYP]<>"11")) )? If the measue dont sums any value, it could display a "0"?

Comment: CALCULATE(SUM(tbl2[QTY]);FILTER(tbl2; tbl2[TYP]<>"11")) + 0

Comment: Allright, with this approach I get every code of the tbl_General. That was not my objective. Maybe it is not possible with the data modell I am working with...

Comment: You could add in some error handling like "QTY2 Display = IF(ABS([QTY1]) + ABS([QTY2]) > 0, [QTY2] + 0, BLANK())" then you can use QTY2 Display in your table. And do something similar for QTY 1 as well. We use display measures all the time in production.