# Power BI: Using a Card to show percentage of grand total

Tags: powerbi

I am looking for a way to show the percentage of total into a Card on Power BI. Anyone has any idea to go about this? Thanks.

Sample Data:

```
Category    Reference
A           123
A           321
A           651
B           468
B           123
```

If I select A in the Slicer, the Card should show 60%, which is 3/5 = 60%.

Comment: did you managed to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a measure that will count total number of rows in your table:

```
 Total Rows = COUNTROWS('Table')
```

Then, create another measure, which will calculate number of occurrences of specific category selected within a slicer, and use this measure as denominator within DIVIDE function:

```
 % of Total = DIVIDE([Total Rows],CALCULATE([Total Rows],ALL('Table'[Category])))
```

Finally, click on this measure and format it as Percentage. Place this measure in card visual and that's it.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I created two columns, Static Entry will hold 1 for each row.
I created another column which will have have formula as

```
 Avg = 'Table (2)'[Static Entry]/COUNT('Table (2)'[Category])
```

[image]

[image]

Note for Percentage symbol below settings and [Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53518931/5436880)

[image]